# How to remove list name from JSON using Jersey 2 / Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

Here is the JSON I am getting now:

```
{
  "popularPurchases": [
    {
      "id": 759415,
       "price": 1186,
      "users": [
        "john.doe",
        "mary.smith",
        "someone.else",
        "some.guy",
        "not.me"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 655062,
      "price": 540,
      "users": [
        "john.doe",
        "jack.john",
        "someone.else"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 546179,
      "price": 670,
      "users": [
        "john.doe",
        "rogbert.lange",
        "smith"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get rid of the "popularPurchases" : before the array. I have tried @JsonUnwrapped, but it is having no affect. I can't even rename it with @XmlElement(name="somethinglese").

I only need the contents of the list without the name of the list.

Comment: Have you tried annotating getPopularPurchases() with `@JsonValue` ?  http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html

Comment: Yes!! That did it!! Thanks!!